# Java Master - remote slave worker library

Tags: java, remoting, agent, slave

I am designing a Java framework that should have a component consisting of a master that can place a slave on a remote machine reachable over ssh. Further once the slave starts it should connect to the master. Finally master should be able to pass serializable POJOs to the slave which will blindly execute and return the result.

I understand that this is an exactly similar requirement, that how Jenkins controller "talks" with its agent nodes. I tried reusing the slave only, but it does not seem straight forward.

In light of this information,

1. Is there an open source framework that offers this already (except JADE)
2. Is there any attempt that already has been taken to use the slave for building this in the OSS community

Comment: It's a few hundred lines of code with RMI, no?